# MYSQL query to show current month records count

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table named "orders" as you can see in the screenshot. I want to get total number of records  in the table as well as the current month's record . I tried

```
 SELECT COUNT(*),COUNT(MONTH(date) = month(CURRENT_DATE())) FROM orders
```

but it returns the total number of records , in this case 8. Also tried to use CASE but that did not work either. I want the result as total_orders = 8 , This Month's Orders=6.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Try `SUM()` instead of `COUNT()`.  The latter tells you how many values there are, but both `TRUE` and `FALSE` are values, only `NULL` "doesn't count".

Comment: this returns this months records but how to  get the total number of records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close, `COUNT()` doesn't only count `TRUE` values, it counts any and all `non-NULL` values, so it's counting the `FALSE` values too.

Try...

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*),
  SUM(DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-01') = DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(), '%Y-%m-01'))
FROM
  orders
```

When summed, `TRUE` is treated as `1`, and `FALSE` is treated as `0`

I also use `DATE_FORMAT()` instead of `MONTH()` so you don't accidentally count the values from the same month in previous years.

- If you want that, just change the `DATE_FORMAT()` back to `MONTH()` and keep the `SUM()`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want total orders and the number of orders in the current calendar month.

You're pretty close.

Try this:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) total,
       SUM(LAST_DAY(date) = LAST_DAY(CURDATE())) this_month
  FROM orders
```

Why does this work?

- The expression `LAST_DAY(date)` gives the last day of the month in which `date` occurs. For example, `LAST_DAY('2021-05-11 13:20:33')` is `2021-05-31 00:00:00`.
- `LAST_DAY(date) = LAST_DAY(CURDATE())` compares the current day's last day to the ones in the table. It yields a Boolean value, which is either `1` for *true* or `0` for *false*.
- SUM(whatever), because you feed it that Boolean, sums up the number of true values of `whatever`.

Using `MONTH(date)` won't work, because it picks up rows in the current month from previous years.

Comment: I would generally avoid suggesting that `SUM()` "counts" things up, the OP already appears confused about what `COUNT()` does and does not do.  The `SUM()` of `1, 2, 3` wouldn't be described as counting them up to `6`, rather it adds them up to `6` *(or "sums" them up to `6`, but I'd presume you were looking for a synonym rather than just saying "sum" again...)* ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try a left join with a dummy column:

```
So:
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT "one" AS dummy, COUNT(*) AS total_orders FROM orders) AS T1 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT "one" AS dummy, COUNT(*) AS this_months_orders FROM orders WHERE MONTH(date_time) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())) AS T2
ON (T1.dummy= T2.dummy);
```

First query counts all rows, second query counts only the current's month rows.